# moderncv "title"-line is simply missing

Tags: moderncv

I'm just missing the title-line "curriculum vitae" in the head of my cv.

thank you very much

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}    

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 

\definecolor{firstnamecolor}{rgb}{0.65,0.65,0.65}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.20,0.40,0.65}
\definecolor{footersymbolcolor}{rgb}{0.65,0.65,0.65}
\definecolor{addresscolor}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}

\quote{Während einer nur Zahlen und Zeichen im Kopf hat, kann er nicht dem Kausalzusammenhang auf die Spur kommen.  -Schopenhauer-}  

\newcommand{\Datum}{\today}
\makeatletter 
   \newcommand{\Unterschrift}{(\@firstname ~\@familyname)}
\nopagenumbers

\firstname{Chris}
\familyname{\textcolor{blue}{Lastname}}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{street}{city}
\mobile{123}
\email{123@hotmail.de}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You don't see "Chris Lastname \\ \hline \\ Curriculum Vitae" in the very top? For me it looks fine. Please specify, what you want. Or draw a picture what is missing where.

Comment: @downvoter I don't think a downvote is best way to welcome someone here...

Comment: Only the words "curriculum vitae" are missing. everything else is fine. Thx!

Comment: I guess you use an old version of your TeX distribution or of class `moderncv`. With MiKTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) and moderncv 2013/04/29 v1.5.1 everything looks fine and I see "curriculum vitae".

Comment: @Chris was that the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue is not reproducible with up-to-date packages.